# [self.addPlayPOP dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; fails when compiled with Xcode 6

Tags: xcode5, xcode6, popover

I upgraded to xcode 6 but kept Xcode 5 as well.

In an app I have a simple line of code to close a popover:
[self.addPlayPOP dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

When I compile and run my app on my iPad using Xcode 5 the code works but
when I compile and run the code using Xcode 6 the code fails or should I say
does nothing.

Both times the app is running on ios8.0.2 but fails only when compiled with Xcode 6.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by reading some other topics on the behavior of Xcode 6.

It seems that Xcode 6 handles property settings differently.

I previously had the following code when setting the property UIPopoverController.

@property (weak) UIPopoverController *addPlayPOP;

it worked great in ios7 and ios8 as long as it was compiled with xcode5.

in xcode6 it seems that weak won't hold the property so I changed it to strong and now it compiles with xcode6. Haven't tried it compiling with xcode5.